# Why does a multiple WHERE clause SQL SELECT statement with two conditions in each clause where one condition has the same value take a long time?

Tags: postgresql, select

I have two different SQL queries I'm running on a Postgres 9.1 database:

```
SELECT device_id, country FROM devices WHERE
(device_id = '97c179bd' AND country = 'US') OR
(device_id = 'bf5f50c6' AND country = 'US') OR
....
(device_id = '0e66c04d' AND country = 'US')
```

12 seconds to run (3620 clauses separated by OR)

and

```
SELECT device_id, country FROM devices WHERE
(device_id = '97c179bd' AND country = 'US') OR
(device_id = 'bf5f50c6' AND country = 'US') OR
....
(device_id = '0e66c04d' AND country = 'US') OR
(device_id = '0e66c04d' AND country = 'different')
```

0.6 seconds to run (3620 clauses separated by OR)

In the first one, the country condition is the same in every clause. In the second one, I switched the country to 'different' in the last clause.

The first select statement takes 12 seconds to run, the second select statement takes 0.6 seconds to run.

In the first query, the CPU is pegged at 100% for almost all of the 12 seconds without any disk reads, indicating it's likely to be the parser that's taking so long. This does not happen with the second query.

I've run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and get the exact same results for how both queries are broken down.

What is going on here? Why does having the second condition be the same in each WHERE clause statement result in a much longer query time?

**EDIT:**

First few lines of EXPLAIN ANALYZE from first query:

Bitmap Heap Scan on devices (cost=18807.49..52584.74 rows=3564 width=39) (actual time=73.994..78.994 rows=3620 loops=1)

Recheck Cond: (((device_id = '97c179bd'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = 'bf5f50c6'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = '3b05d35a'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = 'c6684bc0'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = '0e66c04d'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text))

First few lines of EXPLAIN ANALYZE from second query:

Bitmap Heap Scan on devices (cost=18806.59..85317.68 rows=3563 width=39) (actual time=74.737..79.769 rows=3619 loops=1)

Recheck Cond: (((device_id = '97c179bd'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = 'bf5f50c6'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = '3b05d35a'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = 'c6684bc0'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text)) OR ((device_id = '0e66c04d'::text) AND (country = 'US'::text))

**EDIT 2:**

Here are the two EXPLAIN ANALYZE results:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4747107/explain/query1slow.htm

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4747107/explain/query2fast.htm

Comment: It'd be nice to see your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output here. Which PostgreSQL version?..

Comment: PostgreSQL9.1. I just added the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: Please upload the execution plan to http://explain.depesz.com or at least format it properly (using `<pre>` tags) so that the indention is preserved.

Comment: First few lines will not be enough, full output needed.

Comment: The explain analyze show that both queries take about the same time, under 80ms. Where are you measuring the 12s?

Comment: Here are the two EXPLAIN ANALYZE results: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4747107/explain/query1slow.htm https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4747107/explain/query2fast.htm

Comment: So you know, I believe the majority of time is spent in the parser, NOT in performing execution or reading off of disk, which is why EXPLAIN ANALYZE says its so quick to return

Comment: Since the queries are almost identical, having one being 12 times slower to parse than the other doesn't seem plausible. Another strange thing is why the query with 'different' returns the same number of rows (7244) despite the fact that 'different' shouldn't match any row?

Comment: Yeah I know it seems ridiculous, which is why I came here. I just don't understand it. The only real clue is that the CPU is pegged while running the longer query before any disk is hit (as least as far as I can tell from htop). I'm seeing what other variations of the query have the same behavior. I really don't know how this could happen other than I've hit some weird corner case in PostgreSQL.

I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL by any means- I'm going to get someone else to take a look at this, hopefully they can figure it out. Thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: I'm also not sure what the number 7244 actually represents. I've done the query from both a phpPgAdmin interface and through Python and get the same results. Switching the order of the device_id and country in the last row (country = 'different' AND device_id = '0e66c04d') results in the poor performance time as well.

Answer (score 6):

While not an explanation for the difference in performance, the best solution to this problem will be refactor your query not to use over 3000 `OR` clauses. That's just horrible.

Instead of:

```
SELECT device_id, country FROM devices WHERE
(device_id = '97c179bd' AND country = 'US') OR
(device_id = 'bf5f50c6' AND country = 'US') OR
....
(device_id = '0e66c04d' AND country = 'US')
```

Write:

```
SELECT d.device_id, d.country
FROM devices d 
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
            ('97c179bd','US'),
            ('bf5f50c6','US'),
            ('0e66c04d','US')
) v(device_id,country) USING (device_id,country);
```

Demo setup:

```
create table devices (device_id text, country text, primary key (device_id,country));

insert into devices values 
        ('97c179bd','US'),
        ('bf5f50c6','US'),
        ('0e66c04d','US'),('0e66c04d','different');
```

Demo output:

```
regress=>     SELECT d.device_id, d.country
    FROM devices d 
    INNER JOIN (VALUES 
                ('97c179bd','US'),
                ('bf5f50c6','US'),
                ('0e66c04d','US')
    ) v(device_id,country) USING (device_id,country);
 device_id | country 
-----------+---------
 97c179bd  | US
 bf5f50c6  | US
 0e66c04d  | US
(3 rows)
```

For larger value lists, it may be worth creating a temporary table and `INSERT`ing or `COPY`ing into it, rather than using an in-line `VALUES` list. For truly huge data sets you might benefit from creating a unique index on `device_id,country`.